# C#_WCF Xml Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am serializing object through XMLSerializer ,but every time i invoke the method old data is getting replaced with the new data,i want to append the object every time i invoke not rewrite ,Below is the code which i have written please help me

```
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Employee));
StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\divya.kakumanu\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\XmlFile.xml");               

try
{
    mySerializer.Serialize(stream, emp);
}
catch (SerializationException ex)
{
    throw;
}
finally
{
    stream.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can tell the StreamWriter to append to the file instead of overwriting it using [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
new StreamWriter("your-file-path", **true**);
```

Also...Why are you rethrowing that exception?  And you should really put a [using block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) around the StreamWriter

Comment: Why didn't they work?  Did you get an error or something?  Append should work fine as long as you are closing the file from last time.

Comment: I've tried doing this instead of adding its giving error in xml file XmlSerializer serializer = null;
                FileStream stream = null;
                if (File.Exists("empinfo.xml"))
                {
                        serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Employee));
stream = new FileStream("empinfo.xml", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);serializer.Serialize(stream, e);
stream.Close();}
else
{
  serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Employee));
 stream = new FileStream("empinfo.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
 serializer.Serialize(stream, e);
  stream.Close();}
 }